# Can I use user input to print a variable by name?

Tags: python

I want the user to be able to type a variable name and then print it.

like

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

raw_input("Choose one:")
```

They type "a" and then it prints the contents of the variable `a` instead of just printings the input as a string.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is, but you should probably use a `dict` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put your variables in a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

and then the input is a key that you need to retreive its value from the dictionary.

```
chosen = raw_input("Choose one:")
print dictionary[chosen]
```

Comment: Ok can this method hold a string instead of a int? wouldn't that become cumbersome? Also if I have more than 26ish options then would the dictionary method still be best suited? Thank you!

Comment: @GregoryM dictionaries don't care about the types of values. Just remember that `raw_input` always returns a string

Comment: @Meccano the keys can be anything **hashable**. E.g. not a list.

Comment: Still your keys are strings , not variables .  It should be like this : `dictionary = { 'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c }`  so `dictionary['a']` is `a`